# How to rotate a Torch Tensor by a random number of degrees

Tags: python, rotation, pytorch

as part of training a CNN, I am working with an array `inputs` that contain `<class 'torch.Tensor'>` objects. I want to rotate an individual `<class 'torch.Tensor'>` object by some random number of degrees `x`, as shown here:

```
def rotate(inputs, x):
    # Rotate inputs[0] by x degrees, x can take on any value from 0 - 180 degrees
```

How can I do this? For existing implementations, I can only find that `torch` has a `rot90` function, but that limits me to multiples of `90` degrees which does not help my scenario.

Thanks, Vinny

Comment: There is [`torchvision.transforms.RandomRotation`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.RandomRotation) but it's working on PIL images. I'm not aware of any widespread implementation for `torch.Tensor` objects.

Comment: After rotation there will be black areas. How you plan to do the fill those areas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transform an `torch.tensor` you can use `scipy.ndimage.rotate` function (read [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html)),that rotates a `torch.tensor` but also it converts it to `numpy.ndarray`, so you have to convert it back to `torch.tensor`. See this toy example.

**Function:**

```
def rotate(inputs, x):
    return torch.from_numpy(ndimage.rotate(inputs, x, reshape=False))
```

**Detailed explanation:**

```
import torch
from scipy import ndimage
alpha = torch.rand(3,3)
print(alpha.dtype)#torch.float32

angle_in_degrees = 45
output = ndimage.rotate(alpha, angle_in_degrees, reshape=False)

print(output.dtype) #numpy_array

output = torch.from_numpy(output) #convert it back to torch tensor

print(output.dtype)  #torch.float32
```

Also, You can directly transform PIL image before converting it to tensor if that's a possibility. To transform PIL image you can use PyTorch builtin `torchvision.transforms.functional.rotate` (read [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.functional.rotate)).

Comment: This answer only works when the data is on the CPU. Of course, you could bring the data to the `cpu()` but that is very slow. Any clue of how to rotate a Tensor that is on the GPU?